# Python Loop Reverse Diamond

Tags: python, loops, reverse

I have a code that loops to create a diamond, but I would want it to be reversed.

```
width = int(input("Please enter a width: "))

i = 1
while i < width*2:
    if i < width:
        print("-" * (width-i) + " *" * i + "-" * (width-i))
    else:
        print("-" * (i-width) + " *" * (2*width-i) + "-" * (i-width))
    i += 1 [EDIT: formatting mistake]
```

My output is as follows:

```
---- *----
--- * *---
-- * * *--
- * * * *-
 * * * * *
- * * * *-
-- * * *--
--- * *---
---- *----
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
 * * * * *
- * * * *-
-- * * *--
--- * *---
---- *----
---- *----
--- * *---
-- * * *--
- * * * *-
 * * * * *
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: the i+=1 should be inside the loop, I think that is how you have it, but you just messed up posting it here.

Comment: Did you notice that the reverse diamond is exactly the same as your first diamond, just with the index offset. i.e. its the same as if you used `i` from 4 to 9, then `i` from 0 to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
width = int(input("Please enter a width: "))

i = 0
while i < width*2:
    if i < width:
        print("-" * i+ " *" * (width-i) + "-" * i)
    else:
        print("-" * ((2*width-i) -1) + " *" * (i - width + 1) + "-" *     ((2*width-i) -1))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out! Any tips on how you actually solved it?

Comment: Its simple. I tried to solved it in parts , first step was to draw first half inverted triangle for which i just changed your 'if' block to print inverted diamond and changed your declaration of variable i to 0 as we dont want any '-' for first output line and managed the rest condition accordingly. And then i moved to next half diamond. Logic can be varied as per individual approach, i just managed to use your approach so you don't have to look for different logic